# External hard drive unplugged while running iTunes…Corrupted files

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, itunes

I have nearly 2TB of Movies and TV Shows copied to iTunes on an external hard drive. Last night, I was unplugging a cord behind my desk and I accidentally unplugged my HD. Well, when I plugged it back in and tried to open iTunes, it said that it was corrupted.

I couldn't figure out a work around for this so I made a new iTunes Library and pointed it to my media. I still couldn't get it to recognize my movies etc. This morning I tried to manually open one of the movies with Quicktime player and it says that it is not a movie file. HELP!!! This was days and days of work to transfer my DVD collection over.

I know this should've been backed up. I just finished transferring them and purchased another drive for this purpose. This happened before I was able to back them up.

Comment: Is this on Windows or Mac OS X?

Comment: @James Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

Let's run a chkdsk on the external drive that will hopefully fix your problem.

1. Open My computer, right click your external drive, and click properties
2. Click Tools, then Check Now
3. Check the box to 'automatically fix system errors' and the box 'scan and restore bad sectors'
4. Click Start

Information should appear in the chkdsk window as it performs the check. Hopefully this helps you out!

EDIT: I'm assuming it's a windows box...

Comment: I should've pointed out that I am using a mac.

Comment: There's a baked-in disk repair tool in Mac called Disk Utility. It's not very robust, but I'd give it's repair function a try. You can find it if you search for 'Disk Utility' on your home screen

Comment: I used Disk Utility already without success.

Comment: You might want to give a third party tool a look. Disk Warrior is great, however it's pricey: http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/

Comment: I used Disk Warrior too. It appears that the files are corrupted.

Comment: I hate to say it, but you might have to bring it to a professional to see if any of the data can be extracted. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I guess sometimes, though be it harshly, we are reminded of the fragility of data.